# Apache server return 503 when uploading file

Tags: php, apache-2.4

Why when uploading files of more than 80 MB after a moment my server returns error 503?

[Service Unavailable Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqJjR.png)

any other file of smaller weight uploads it without problems. Im using apache server in web hosting with this config in php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = -1
max_input_time = -1
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 1G
```

Comment: Read the error logs on the server.

Comment: The logs is:
`Cannot serve directory /home/domainname/public_html/public/libros/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php5,index.php4,index.php3,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.jp,index.phtml,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.html,index.htm,index.wml,Default.html,Default.htm,default.html,default.htm,home.html,home.htm,index.js) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`